# How to use basic AUTH in msoffice uri scheme?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, basic-authentication, webdav

When prefixing the url with msofficeuri basic authentication no longer works and application asks for the username,password.

Example:

Appending credentials to an url works perfectly:

```
https://user:pass@someurl.com/webdav/somefile.docx
```

But once I use msword urischeme, the MsWord asks for password all the time:

```
ms-word:ofe|u|https://user:pass@someurl.com/webdav/somefile.docx
```

The official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes) doesn't help much, doesn't even mention authentication.

All I want to achieve is that users shouldnt be prompted for login credentials.